# What is Gor'kov potential?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, ultrasound

I'm studying acoustic levitation and have come across this term called "Gor'kov Potential" and did not know what it was. I did a Google search but all I found was research papers loosly defining the term which I couldn't understand. So can anybody please explain what Gor'kov potential is. With diagrams if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

So, first: As waves travel trough the fluid and scatter on impact with a particle, the particle gets pushed away. This acting force is called acoustic radiation force (ARF), and was first described by King in 1934. Some years later Gor'kov revised the formula and said, that this force is (like) a potential force U and therefore also called Gor'kov potental. It depends on density, compressability and geometry, etc. In the end, the ARF pushes a particle to the gor'kov minimum potential, which can be used to concentrate particles.

If you want more background info, check the book by henrik bruus on microscale acoustofluidics for that.
Hope I could help :)